# What is #! doing before all my routes in Meteor? (Using iron-router)

Tags: meteor, iron-router

My routes have started appearing in the form:
http://localhost:3000/#!team/Wdv9zGinoMbp5a7cj

The addition of the #! must be quite new. What is it? And why was it added? Did a package that I added cause this? Or was it an Iron Router update that did it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally due to the `appcache` package. See [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/meteor-core/appcache$20iron-router/meteor-core/bUTOXugc5qE/QOmlSjZxwFYJ).

Comment: Thanks. I did add appcache recently. Thought it might be that